# Python Selenium: Getting StaleElementReferenceException on click for SPA website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to extract 1000 usernames and the team rosters for each username in a list  from this SPA (single page application) sports website (requires free login): https://rumble.otmnft.com/contest/live?contest=Rumble

I've tried numerous strategies to try to avoid the common StaleElementReferenceException problem in Selenium including `try / except` block, `WebDriverWait` and `time.sleep(5)` among many others, but none have worked. Would be amazing if someone knows an alternative solution which could work as I've been trying to solve this by myself for quite a few days now.

Here is the relevant part of the latest attempted code which still throws StaleElementReferenceException below:

```
parent_dict = {}
    parent_dict['data'] = []

    USERNAME_XPATH = "//span[@class='hidden lg:flex font-semibold']"
    ROSTER_XPATH = "//span[@class='text-white hidden lg:flex font-semibold']"

    WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table")))  
    username_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, USERNAME_XPATH)

    try:
        for usr_element in username_elements:
            usr_element.click()                 
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        # Find the element again and continue with the loop         
        WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, USERNAME_XPATH))) 
        username_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, USERNAME_XPATH)
        time.sleep(5)
        for usr_element in username_elements:
            usr_element.click()         

    WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ROSTER_XPATH)))
    roster_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ROSTER_XPATH)
    roster = [cell.text for cell in roster_elements]
    TITLE_USER_XPATH = "//div[@class='flex flex-col space-y-2']/span"
    title_user = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, TITLE_USER_XPATH)            
    child_dict = {"username": title_user.text, "roster": roster }
    print("CHILD_DICT", child_dict)

    parent_dict['data'].append(child_dict)
    with open('data_v2.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(parent_dict, outfile)
    print("PARENT_DICT", parent_dict)           
    return parent_dict
```

In the browser I can see that the script is able to click on the very first username but it fails when trying click on the second username, but reports the error for the line `usr_element.click()` both inside the `try` and `except` blocks

Full error trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/danpro12/Dropbox/01 FREE TIME STUFF/01 WEB DEVELOPMENT/12 DAPPER RELATED/otm_python_scraper/otm_specific/utils.py", line 23, in sub_func
    usr_element.click()
  File "/Users/danpro12/.virtualenvs/otm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 88, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Users/danpro12/.virtualenvs/otm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 396, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/danpro12/.virtualenvs/otm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/danpro12/.virtualenvs/otm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <span class="hidden lg:flex font-semibold"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:180:5
StaleElementReferenceError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:461:5
element.resolveElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:674:11
evaluate.fromJSON@chrome://remote/content/marionette/evaluate.sys.mjs:255:31
evaluate.fromJSON@chrome://remote/content/marionette/evaluate.sys.mjs:263:29
receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:74:34


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/danpro12/Dropbox/01 FREE TIME STUFF/01 WEB DEVELOPMENT/12 DAPPER RELATED/otm_python_scraper/otm_specific/rumble_client.py", line 53, in <module>
    sub_func(driver)
  File "/Users/danpro12/Dropbox/01 FREE TIME STUFF/01 WEB DEVELOPMENT/12 DAPPER RELATED/otm_python_scraper/otm_specific/utils.py", line 30, in sub_func
    usr_element.click()
  File "/Users/danpro12/.virtualenvs/otm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 88, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Users/danpro12/.virtualenvs/otm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 396, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/danpro12/.virtualenvs/otm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/danpro12/.virtualenvs/otm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <span class="hidden lg:flex font-semibold"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:180:5
StaleElementReferenceError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:461:5
element.resolveElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:674:11
evaluate.fromJSON@chrome://remote/content/marionette/evaluate.sys.mjs:255:31
evaluate.fromJSON@chrome://remote/content/marionette/evaluate.sys.mjs:263:29
receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:74:34
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that after you do `usr_element.click()` DOM updated and so you cannot iterate over `username_elements` since all elements in this list are stale.

Try this solution

```
username_elements_length = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, USERNAME_XPATH))
for usr_element_index in range(username_elements_length):
    username_element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, USERNAME_XPATH)[usr_element_index]
    username_element.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.staleness_of(username_element))
```

Comment: Thanks v. much! That appears to be working now that I put that inside both try and except blocks. Can you explain a bit more why using the index and range here will ensure that the elements remain "fresh" ie. not stale lol? Thanks again!

Comment: Whoops, spoke a bit too soon. Failed on user number 102 with same stale element error on the same .click() line.

Comment: @neo5_50 that might be if you made a click but the page was not refreshed instantly... try updated code and let me know if problem still exist

Comment: Don't worry it was a separate issue where I had to scroll each element into view. That's fixed now. Answer accepted, thanks again!